# Нужно запушить данные из массива с индексами которые даны в другом массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы, for, foreach

Нужна помощь с циклами, не получается сопоставить всё вместе, чтобы работало.
Мне нужно по очереди пушить данные из массива `needToPush` с индексами из массива `index`, в массив объектов `players`.
То есть на каждой итерации должны в `player1` заходить данные `needToPush[index[0]]` ---> `needToPush[index[1]]`. Далее в `player2` `needToPush[index[2]]` и тд.

```
let players = [
    { player1: [] },
    { player2: [] },
    { player3: [] },
];
```

```
const needToPush = ['eee', 'push1', 'www', 'push2', 'qqq', 'push3', 'push4', 'rrr', 'push5', 'push6', 'ghj', 'xcv'];
```

```
const index = [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9];
```

В конце должно получится такое:

```
let players = [
    { player1: ['push1', 'push2'] },
    { player2: ['push3', 'push4'] },
    { player3: ['push5', 'push6'] },
];
```

Comment: Покажите что вы писали и что из этого не получилось.......вообще надо проходить по массиву `index` а не `needToPush`, т.к. второй явно больше по размерам

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я пытался писать через 2 цикла for и использовать переменные из цикла соответственно как индексы. Писал через for а потом через forEach, но forEach метод не сочетается с push методом. Потом я зашёл в тупик так, как я кроме как через forEach, не знаю как получить доступ к ключу объекта для пуша данных

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из вариантов, т.к. нет точного указателя, кому что должно принадлежать.
Сделал из условия, что каждому игроку из списка добавляется по 2 значения и далее идем к следующему.

Так нет проверок, что закончился массив с индексами и данными(желательно поставить, если точные длины массивов могут отличаться.

```js
let players = [
  { player1: [] },
  { player2: [] },
  { player3: [] },
];

const needToPush = ['eee', 'push1', 'www', 'push2', 'qqq', 'push3', 'push4', 'rrr', 'push5', 'push6', 'ghj', 'xcv'];
const index = [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9];

let i = 0;
let id = 1;
index.forEach((item) => {
  const play = 'player' + id;
  players[id-1][play].push(needToPush[item]);
  i++;
  if (!(i % 2)) {
    i = 0;
    id++;
  }
})

console.log(players);
```